# How to set extent of map for list of coordinates using ArcGIS JavaScript API

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, coordinates, extents

I am trying to set the extent for my ArcGIS map using the JavaScript API built in. Here's my code:

```
              const [Extent] = await loadModules(["esri/geometry/Extent"]);
              let response = new Extent();
              for (const datum of dataPoints) {
                let resExtent = new Extent(
                  datum.latitude,
                  datum.longitude,
                  datum.latitude,
                  datum.longitude,
                  response.spatialReference
                );
                response = await response.union(resExtent);
              }
              viewRef.current.goTo(response);
```

And my datum list is an array of coordinates such as: `[..., {latitude: XXX, longitude: XXX}, ...]`. The above code plots the coordinates on the map but the extent is not correct with issues like some points lie in the boundary of the map.

How can I resolve this issue ?

Comment: What are the spatial reference of the extent and the map?

Comment: Could you explain (maybe a screenshot) what you mean with "the extent is not correct with issues like some points lie in the boundary of the map"? Do you just need the map to zoom out a little bit?

Comment: Yes @BjornSvensson you are correct...I need to zoom out a bit to actually see those points. Also the points are not getting placed exactly at the center of my map....they are displaced somewhat towards left

Comment: Have you viewed Arcgis developers page? Here is the link: https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jshelp/intro_extents.html

Answer (score 1):

You can expand your Extent a little to make sure that it zooms out a bit more. See https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-geometry-Extent.html#expand
`viewRef.current.goTo(response.clone().expand(1.5));`

Another aspect is that by default, the mapView will "snap" to the different zoom levels. It's possible that this snaps to a zoom level too far zoomed in. You can turn off this "snap to zoom" behavior by setting the `constraints.snapToZoom` to false when you create the mapView.
See https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-views-MapView.html#constraints